# best api for develop with maps web application google-maps vs bing-maps

Tags: google-maps, maps, bing-maps

i'm need to develop and web application that uses maps, and i have two option in my to reach the goal. Google maps or bing maps, my concern it's witch it's better about

1. Documentation it's very important
2. Implementation with a Web application develop in .net
3. Fast learning curve

i need recommendations because for my point of view both are a completed tools for solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I strongly recommend Google Maps.

1. [Fabulous documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/)
2. [Code Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/)
3. Very fast learning curve
4. With the new v3 api you don't need a api key

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

take a look at our series of articles comparing aspects of both, and Ill admit up front I like bing more but have tried to be as impartial as possible:

http://www.earthware.co.uk/blog/index.php/2011/02/ajax-mapping-apis-google-maps-vs-bing-maps-update-pushpin-display-performance/

http://www.earthware.co.uk/blog/index.php/2010/12/mapping-apis-google-maps-vs-bing-maps-update-api-download-sizes/

and the original posts:

http://www.earthware.co.uk/blog/index.php/2009/12/mapping-apis-google-maps-vs-bing-maps-part-1-introduction/

http://www.earthware.co.uk/blog/index.php/2009/12/mapping-apis-google-maps-vs-bing-maps-part-2-licensing/

http://www.earthware.co.uk/blog/index.php/2010/01/mapping-apis-google-maps-vs-bing-maps-part-4-developer-support-community/